# How do I make my ReactJs app display A different message when In different screens?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have to clone a website using ReactJs which only works on desktop. When it is viewed in a mobile view or Tablet...it shows  "SITE NOT AVAILABLE ON MOBILE". I want to do that too....but it is not working on my site

```js
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Text from "./components/Text";
import Slider from "./components/Slider";
import Wallet from "./components/Wallet";
import Dropdown from "./components/Dropdown";
import MobileTablet from "./components/MobileTablet";
import { BrowserView, MobileView } from "react-device-detect";

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserView>
        <Router>
          <Text />
          <div className="box">
            <Navbar />
            <Dropdown />
            <div className="box2">
              <Slider />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="box3">
            <Wallet />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </BrowserView>
      <MobileView>
        <MobileTablet />
      </MobileView>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the code for App.js the main part....Can someone help me make my app responsive...since i am very new to this.
If you need any other codes pls let me know

Comment: As I can see you're using `react-device-detect`, and IDK what kind of error you're facing, i think you'd better follow document with their example first before finding what is root cause

Comment: There is no error but it is not displaying the message i want it to either. And i did refer to their documentation

Comment: Did you try their `isMobile` for conditional rendering ?

Comment: Use "react-device-detect" or CSS media query to hide and show your content, or using bootstrap classes "d-none d-md-block" and "d-block d-md-none"

Answer (score 0):

Look, you can use a State to monitor the viewport of client window, then a useEffect to change it. The property window.innerWidth gives you the width of the client, and then you can specify it to work only under specific conditions:

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [userIsDesktop, setUserIsDesktop] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    window.innerWidth > 1280 ? setUserIsDesktop(true) : setUserIsDesktop(false);
  }, [userIsDesktop]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {userIsDesktop ? <h1>i'm a desktop</h1> : <h1>i'm a mobile</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: 1920 is full HD screen
so in a normal desktop screen it will show mobile UI!!
Consider normal old desktop monitors which start from 1280, ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `isMobile` for conditional rendering

```
import {isMobile} from 'react-device-detect';
...

    if (isMobile) {
        return <MobileTablet />
    }


``
```